# SFTP methods in python to get basename and full path for files

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I want to download files from an SFTP site in Python, but I want to apply filter to the files first, eg. only download files that fit a certain pattern. I only want to apply the filter to the file name, and not the full path. But when I want to download the file, I need the full path. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: There are a few things I've considered. I know os.path.basename(file) will give me just the file name, but I'm unsure on how to obtain the full file path again. I could also store the full file paths in a separate list, apply my filter to the list with just the file names, and then match the lists against each other, but I'd preferably like something simpler and cleaner if at all possible.

Comment: @JonMartin Just call your filter with the result of `os.path.basename()` and keep the original string.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you are asking here. I am attaching a block of code that gets a list of remote files, then local files, and then I use that to come up with a list of files to be transferred (meaning that the files were in remote dir and not in the local dir this is opposite to the function that puts files). Then it loops through and only transfers files that meet the file filter.

```
def getFiles ( remotePath, filterValue, hostname, user, pwd, pathShare, remove ):
    srv = sftpfunc (hostname,user,pwd)
    retFiles = []
    srv.chdir(remotePath)
    remoteFiles = srv.listdir()
    localFiles = os.listdir(pathShare)
    files = srv.listdir()
    removeMe = ""
    if (len(remoteFiles) > 0):
            tranFiles = list(set(remoteFiles) - set(localFiles))
            print ('File Transfer List: ')
            for fileName in tranFiles:
                    if not filterValue in fileName: continue
                    print ('Transfering:  ',fileName)
                    srv.get(fileName, pathShare+fileName)
                    if (remove):
                            try:
                                    srv.rmfiles(fileName)
                            finally:
                                    print('Could not remove files')

                    retFiles.append(fileName)
    srv.close()
    return retFiles
```